# Concurrent access to static method

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that contains 2 ArcProgress , both of them get data from seperate childs from Firebase, so I created a static method in a seperate Class that change values of Arcs and then call it on the firebase's onDataChange method. The problem that the arcs shows wrong values and I think that is caused by a concurrent access to that class.
I tried to add **synchronized** but that doesn't solve the problem.

This is the class that contains the method

```
public class ArcProgSettings {

private static int diff=0;
private static int i;
private static CountDownTimer waitTimer;
private int previousTemp=0;
private int newT=0;
private ArcProgress arcTemp;

public ArcProgSettings(){
 }

public ArcProgSettings(int previousTemp, int newT, final ArcProgress 
arcTemp){

    this.previousTemp=previousTemp;
    this.newT=newT;
    this.arcTemp=arcTemp;
}



public synchronized void setProg() {
     diff = newT - previousTemp;
     i = previousTemp;


        if (diff >= 0) {
            waitTimer = new CountDownTimer((diff + 2) * 100, 100) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    //called every 300 milliseconds, which could be used to
                    //send messages or some other action
                    arcTemp.setProgress(i);
                    i++;
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    //After 60000 milliseconds (60 sec) finish current
                    //if you would like to execute something when time 
finishes
                }
            }.start();
        } else {
            waitTimer = new CountDownTimer(-(diff - 2) * 100, 100) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    arcTemp.setProgress(i);
                    i--;
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                }
            }.start();


    }
  }
}
```

and this is the Activity that contains the calls:(setProg)

```
public class VisualisationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArcProgress arcTemp;
private DatabaseReference mTempDatabase;
private String MyTemp="0";
int previousTemp=0;

private ArcProgress arcCurrent;
private DatabaseReference mCurrentDatabase;
private String MyCurrent="0";
int previousCurrent=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_visualisation);
    arcTemp=(ArcProgress)findViewById(R.id.arc_prog_temp);
    mTempDatabase = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("temp");



    mTempDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            MyTemp =(dataSnapshot.child("value").getValue().toString());
            final int newT= Integer.parseInt(MyTemp);
            ArcProgSettings arc=new ArcProgSettings(previousTemp, 
newT,arcTemp);
            arc.setProg();

            previousTemp=newT;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    arcCurrent=(ArcProgress)findViewById(R.id.arc_progress_current);
    mCurrentDatabase = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("current");


    mCurrentDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            MyCurrent =(dataSnapshot.child("value").getValue().toString());
            final int newC= Integer.parseInt(MyCurrent);
            ArcProgSettings arc1=new ArcProgSettings(previousCurrent, 
newC,arcCurrent);
            arc1.setProg();

            previousCurrent=newC;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need separate timers and progress for each listener, why to use static variables? (waitTimer, diff, i). The problem is that both instances of ArcProgress are updating the same values, its not concurrency, is design. Change your variables to make it private only and you'll se a different result.